# Continuous function on Polish space

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

I want to prove the following and have no idea how to proceed:

For a continuous function $f: X \mapsto Y$ where $X$ is Polish and $Y$ is Hausdorff the following are equivalent:

1. $f[X]$ is uncountable
2. There is a a perfect set $P \subset X$ such that $f|_p$ is one-to-one.
3. There is a countable set $Q \subset X$ with no isolated points such that $f|_Q$ is one-to-one.

It 'smells' like the Cantor–Bendixson Theorem, but have no idea how to use it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT:

This is as far as I can go in proving it. I will use the following theorems from *Srivastava, A course on Borel sets* (loosely cited):

> 2.6.1 Every dense-in-itself Polish space $X$ contains a copy of $2^\omega$
>
> 2.6.2 (Cantor – Bendixson theorem) Every separable metric
>   space $X$ can be written as $X = P \cup Q$ where $Q$ is countable, $P$ is perfect, and $P,Q$ are disjoint.
>
> 2.6.7 Let $E$ be a closed equivalence relation on a Polish space
>   $X$ with uncountably many equivalence classes. Then there is a copy of $2^\omega$ in X consisting of pairwise inequivalent elements.

2) $\Rightarrow$ 1)

There is perfect $P \subset X$ on which function is one to one. It contains homeomorph of $2^\omega$ and is separable, so $P$ is of cardinality $\mathfrak c$. Hence $|f[X]| \geq | f [P] | = |P| = \mathfrak c$

1) $\Rightarrow$ 2)

1. By AC we choose one element from each nonempty layer $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$. We sum them up, acquiring uncountable $A \subset X$. Using C-B theorem we write it as $A = P \cup Q$ where $P$ is nonempty (because $A$ is uncountable and $Q$ is countable) set, perfect in $A$. Problem is that we are not sure if it is perfect in $X$. But $P$ is dense-in-itself, so ***if it was a $G_\delta$ set*** it would be a Polish space (Aleksandrov theorem). Hence it would contain a copy $D$ of $2^\omega$. Cantor set is perfect and $D$ is closed in $X$ by compactness hence it is perfect set in $X$, the one that we are looking for.
2. ***Suppose*** that layers of $f$ induce ***closed equivalence relationship*** on $X$. Then there exists copy of Cantor set with one element in each equivalence class. By previous argument it is the perfect set we are looking for.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to assure the assumptions I am using. Any help/ideas?

Comment: This would have an interesting corollary: Every continuous function from a Polish space into $\omega_1$ (with the order topology) is bounded. Is this true?

Comment: I can't see how that corollary is implied by this theorem. What is true? This theorem was on my DST homework list, i suppose it is valid.

Comment: Actually, what I said is not quite correct. But if CH is false it holds indeed, because $Y =\omega_1 $ is Hausdorff and any perfect subset of a Polish has cardinality of the continuum. Hence, the range can't be uncountable, and therefore it must be bounded.

Comment: Yes, now it makes sense. :) I think i have proved the equivalence of two first conditions, not that hard. I can post it tomorrow if You are interested.

Comment: Please do so. I think that's the most difficult part.

Comment: When i started writing it down it occurred to me that i HAVE'NT proved it. I edit to show how far i can go. Sorry for misleading You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sketch for (1) implies (2): Fix $A \subseteq X$ be uncountable such that $f \upharpoonright A$ is one-one.  By deleting at most countably many points from $A$ we can assume that every point of $A$ is a condensation point of $A$ - Recall that $x$ is a condensation point of $A$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains uncountably many points of $A$. Now define a tree $\langle B_{\sigma} : \sigma \in 2^{< \omega} \rangle$ such that the following hold: $B_{\phi} = X$, $B_{\sigma 0}, B_{\sigma 1}$ are disjoint closed balls contained in $B_{\sigma}$, $f[B_{\sigma 0}] \cap f[B_{\sigma_1}] = \phi$ and radius of $B_{\sigma} $ is at most $2^{-n}$. To guide this construction, always keep the centers of your balls in $A$. That $Y$ is Hausdorff helps you satisfy $f[B_{\sigma 0}] \cap f[B_{\sigma_1}] = \phi$. Finally your perfect set is simply all the points that lie in the intersection of a branch in $\langle B_{\sigma} : \sigma \in 2^{< \omega} \rangle$. It should be clear that $f$ is one-one on this perfect set.

Hope this helped :)

@Pedro's comment: You don't need $\neg CH$ to conclude that the range of any continuous function from a second countable space to $\omega_1$ is bounded. Just use the fact that every unbounded subset of $\omega_1$ contains uncountably many pairwise disjoint open sets.

Comment: I saw this by chance, and I'm glad of learning from your reply. Next time, try to answer (also) in the comment section, so that people gets noticed by your observations!

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Unregistered users cannot comment except on their answers thanks to the rule-makers.

Comment: @hot_queen Oh, I see. Seems reasonable, that may induce people to register. Thanks.